# Selection following LongClick and Click in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I would like to delete an item from a list if I LONGCLICK, and move an item to another list if I just CLICK. Can AfterPicking make the difference between those two click types, and then carry out the respective actions? Any other solution to the problem is also welcome

Answer (score 0):

The listpicker only offers simple click events.

What you can do is to use 2 listpicker with the same list. Keep the list in a global variable and assign it to the listpickers in the `BeforePicking` event. Use the `Listpicker1.AfterPicking` event to delete items and `Listpicker2.AfterPicking` event to move items.

[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)